# Hash Provider in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

I've followed [this tutorial](http://findnerd.com/list/view/Creating-a-custom-password-encrypt-for-Auth-in-laravel-5-0/3702/) to create a custom hash and I've implemented Multi-Auth system in Laravel 5.3 too (works fine) but I want to know:

Can I use multiple DB hashes between these authentications?

1. Admin Area (I can use bycrypt by default)
2. Customer Area (I can use md5 for example)

Is that possible?

Before you ask: Yes, that's necessary for my project!

Comment: Anyone else? to give me an answer? =o

Comment: Please do not ever use `md5` to hash user passwords. If you can, `password_hash` is always encouraged.

Comment: I understand. But I can't remake the project, so I need to use md5 or sha1 for the customer area. I can only use bycrpt or password_hash for Admin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you already have a working multi auth system and an extra hasher that uses md5, you can inject it in your custom auth provider. Here are possible steps you might require.

If you only want another hasher you may try using core provider:

1. Create a `My\Library\MyHasher` implementing core contract https://github.com/illuminate/contracts/blob/master/Hashing/Hasher.php (as in the tutorial)
2. Register / inject it in the AuthServiceProvider boot method under your app's providers, something like that:

   // instantiate or inject the new hasher as $hasher

   Auth::provider('md5user', function($app, array $config) use ($hasher) {
           return new \Illuminate\Auth\EloquentUserProvider\EloquentUserProvider($hasher, $config['model']);
   });

If you want to be able to tweak the provider functionality:

1. Create a `My\Library\MyUserProvider` similar to a core one https://github.com/illuminate/auth/blob/master/EloquentUserProvider.php and change what you need
2. Create a `My\Library\MyHasher` implementing core contract https://github.com/illuminate/contracts/blob/master/Hashing/Hasher.php
3. Register / inject them in the AuthServiceProvider boot method under your app's providers:

   // instantiate or inject the new hasher as $hasher

   Auth::provider('md5user', function($app, array $config) use ($hasher) {
           return new \My\Library\MyUserProvider($hasher, $config['model']);
   });